# Django create user account via URL

Tags: python, django, authentication, url

I'm currently working with some people to develop an application that will display a "sound library" when the user selects an option on their voip phone. The idea is that the phone system will pass a url with a device id in it, and that will open the django app to the users' library. I was told to remove login/user authentication in order to make the process easier for the user. My question is, is there a way to create a user field and save the model for future retrieval via the url request alone? Do I need to pass the device id to some hidden form first and redirect to the main page, and query the users' objects via the device id? I know there are security concerns but was wondering if it's even possible, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should try using Djago REST Framework, it will make it easy to retrieve data with urls using unique identifier.